# Kotlin: withContext() vs Async-await

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have been reading [kotlin docs](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/coroutines-guide.md), and if I understood correctly the two Kotlin functions work as follows :

1. `withContext(context)`: switches the context of the current coroutine, when the given block executes, the coroutine switches back to previous context.
2. `async(context)`: Starts a new coroutine in the given context and if we call `.await()` on the returned `Deferred` task, it will suspends the calling coroutine and resume when the block executing inside the spawned coroutine returns.

Now for the following two versions of `code` :

**Version1:**

```
  launch(){
    block1()
    val returned = async(context){
      block2()
    }.await()
    block3()
  }
```

**Version2:**

```
  launch(){
    block1()
     val returned = withContext(context){
      block2()
    }
    block3()
  }
```

1. In both versions block1(), block3() execute in default context(commonpool?) where as block2() executes in the given context.
2. The overall execution is synchronous with block1() -> block2() -> block3() order.
3. Only difference I see is that version1 creates another coroutine, where as version2 executes only one coroutine while switching context.

My questions are :

1. Isn't it always better to use `withContext` rather than `async-await` as it is functionally similar, but doesn't create another coroutine. Large numbers of coroutines, although lightweight, could still be a problem in demanding applications.
2. Is there a case `async-await` is more preferable to `withContext`?

**Update:**
[Kotlin 1.2.50](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2018/06/kotlin-1-2-50-is-out/) now has a code inspection where it can convert `async(ctx) { }.await() to withContext(ctx) { }`.

Comment: I think when you use `withContext`, a new coroutine is always created regardless. This is what I can see from the source code.

Comment: @stdout Doesn't `async/await` also create a new coroutine, according to OP?

Answer (score 157, accepted):

> Large number of coroutines, though lightweight, could still be a problem in demanding applications

I'd like to dispel this myth of "too many coroutines" being a problem by quantifying their actual cost.

First, we should disentangle the *coroutine* itself from the *coroutine context* to which it is attached. This is how you create just a coroutine with minimum overhead:

```
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Unconfined) {
    suspendCoroutine<Unit> {
        continuations.add(it)
    }
}
```

The value of this expression is a `Job` holding a suspended coroutine. To retain the continuation, we added it to a list in the wider scope.

I benchmarked this code and concluded that it allocates **140 bytes** and takes **100 nanoseconds** to complete. So that's how lightweight a coroutine is.

For reproducibility, this is the code I used:

```
fun measureMemoryOfLaunch() {
    val continuations = ContinuationList()
    val jobs = (1..10_000).mapTo(JobList()) {
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Unconfined) {
            suspendCoroutine<Unit> {
                continuations.add(it)
            }
        }
    }
    (1..500).forEach {
        Thread.sleep(1000)
        println(it)
    }
    println(jobs.onEach { it.cancel() }.filter { it.isActive})
}

class JobList : ArrayList<Job>()

class ContinuationList : ArrayList<Continuation<Unit>>()
```

This code starts a bunch of coroutines and then sleeps so you have time to analyze the heap with a monitoring tool like VisualVM. I created the specialized classes `JobList` and `ContinuationList` because this makes it easier to analyze the heap dump.

---

To get a more complete story, I used the code below to also measure the cost of `withContext()` and `async-await`:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import kotlin.coroutines.suspendCoroutine
import kotlin.system.measureTimeMillis

const val JOBS_PER_BATCH = 100_000

var blackHoleCount = 0
val threadPool = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()!!
val ThreadPool = threadPool.asCoroutineDispatcher()

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    try {
        measure("just launch", justLaunch)
        measure("launch and withContext", launchAndWithContext)
        measure("launch and async", launchAndAsync)
        println("Black hole value: $blackHoleCount")
    } finally {
        threadPool.shutdown()
    }
}

fun measure(name: String, block: (Int) -> Job) {
    print("Measuring $name, warmup ")
    (1..1_000_000).forEach { block(it).cancel() }
    println("done.")
    System.gc()
    System.gc()
    val tookOnAverage = (1..20).map { _ ->
        System.gc()
        System.gc()
        var jobs: List<Job> = emptyList()
        measureTimeMillis {
            jobs = (1..JOBS_PER_BATCH).map(block)
        }.also { _ ->
            blackHoleCount += jobs.onEach { it.cancel() }.count()
        }
    }.average()
    println("$name took ${tookOnAverage * 1_000_000 / JOBS_PER_BATCH} nanoseconds")
}

fun measureMemory(name:String, block: (Int) -> Job) {
    println(name)
    val jobs = (1..JOBS_PER_BATCH).map(block)
    (1..500).forEach {
        Thread.sleep(1000)
        println(it)
    }
    println(jobs.onEach { it.cancel() }.filter { it.isActive})
}

val justLaunch: (i: Int) -> Job = {
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Unconfined) {
        suspendCoroutine<Unit> {}
    }
}

val launchAndWithContext: (i: Int) -> Job = {
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Unconfined) {
        withContext(ThreadPool) {
            suspendCoroutine<Unit> {}
        }
    }
}

val launchAndAsync: (i: Int) -> Job = {
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Unconfined) {
        async(ThreadPool) {
            suspendCoroutine<Unit> {}
        }.await()
    }
}
```

This is the typical output I get from the above code:

```
Just launch: 140 nanoseconds
launch and withContext : 520 nanoseconds
launch and async-await: 1100 nanoseconds
```

Yes, `async-await` takes about twice as long as `withContext`, but it's still just a microsecond. You'd have to launch them in a tight loop, doing almost nothing besides, for that to become "a problem" in your app.

Using `measureMemory()` I found the following memory cost per call:

```
Just launch: 88 bytes
withContext(): 512 bytes
async-await: 652 bytes
```

The cost of `async-await` is exactly 140 bytes higher than `withContext`, the number we got as the memory weight of one coroutine. This is just a fraction of the complete cost of setting up the `CommonPool` context.

If performance/memory impact was the only criterion to decide between `withContext` and `async-await`, the conclusion would have to be that there's no relevant difference between them in 99% of real use cases.

The real reason is that `withContext()` a simpler and more direct API, especially in terms of exception handling:

- An exception that isn't handled within `async { ... }` causes its parent job to get cancelled. This happens regardless of how you handle exceptions from the matching `await()`. If you haven't prepared a `coroutineScope` for it, it may bring down your entire application.
- An exception not handled within `withContext { ... }` simply gets thrown by the `withContext` call, you handle it just like any other.

`withContext` also happens to be optimized, leveraging the fact that you're suspending the parent coroutine and awaiting on the child, but that's just an added bonus.

`async-await` should be reserved for those cases where you actually want concurrency, so that you launch several coroutines in the background and only then await on them. In short:

- `async-await-async-await` — don't do that, use `withContext-withContext`
- `async-async-await-await` — that's the way to use it.

Comment: Regarding the extra memory cost of `async-await`: When we use `withContext`, a new coroutine is also created (as far as I can see from the source code) so do you think the difference might be coming from somewhere else?

Comment: @stdout The library has been evolving since I ran these tests. The code in the answer is supposed to be fully self-contained, try running it again to validate. `async` creates a `Deferred` object, that may also explain some of the difference.

Comment: ~"**To retain the continuation**".  When do we need to retain this?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky It is always retained but usually not in a way visible to the user. Losing the continuation is equivalent to `Thread.destroy()` -- execution vanishing into thin air.

Answer (score 35):

> Isn't it always better to use withContext rather than asynch-await as it is funcationally similar, but doesn't create another coroutine. Large numebrs coroutines, though lightweight could still be a problem in demanding applications
>
> Is there a case asynch-await is more preferable to withContext

You should use async/await when you want to execute multiple tasks concurrently, for example:

```
runBlocking {
    val deferredResults = arrayListOf<Deferred<String>>()

    deferredResults += async {
        delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        "1"
    }

    deferredResults += async {
        delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        "2"
    }

    deferredResults += async {
        delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        "3"
    }

    //wait for all results (at this point tasks are running)
    val results = deferredResults.map { it.await() }
    //Or val results = deferredResults.awaitAll()
    println(results)
}
```

If you don't need to run multiple tasks concurrently you can use withContext.

Answer (score 27):

When in doubt, remember this like a rule of thumb:

1. If multiple tasks have to happen in parallel and the final result depends on completion of all of them, then use `async`.
2. For returning the result of a single task, use `withContext`.

Comment: Are both `async` and `withContext` blocking in a suspend scope?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky If you are talking about blocking of main thread, `async` and `withContext` won't block the main thread, they will only suspend the body of the coroutine while some long running task is running and waiting for a result. For more info and example see this article on Medium: [Async Operations with Kotlin Coroutines](https://proandroiddev.com/async-operations-with-kotlin-coroutines-part-1-c51cc581ad33).