# Why use withContext() vs Async-await, isn't the goal of coroutines to achieve concurrency?

Tags: android, kotlin, async-await, concurrency

I am learning about threading and kotlin coroutines to load my UI and repository concurrently, but then "withContext()" as an alternative to async-await.
If I understood "withContext()" correctly and it executes one task after another waiting for the previous task to finish, why ever use it? Is there another concept I'm missing?

Comment: Where did you see that `withContext` was an alternative to async await?

Comment: Aren't they apples and oranges? `withContext()` is for changing the context. `async()` is for asynchronous execution. Different purpose, different use cases. Why to compare them in the first place?

Comment: @extremeoats Could you please clarify your question? Are you looking for use cases for `withContext`? Or do you also not see how it's different from `async`?

Comment: @broot if you ever write `async{ .. }` immediately followed by `await()` then you get a warning that suggests replacing it with `withContext`, maybe that's where the question is coming from.

Comment: @Pawel good point, that might be the source of the confusion

Comment: @Joffrey I was looking at different sources but these are 2: https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/withcontext-vs-async-await and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50230466/kotlin-withcontext-vs-async-await. I must have misunderstood it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`withContext` is a suspending function that allows to execute a specific piece of code in a different coroutine context. It is in particular useful when you want to execute something in a different dispatcher.

For instance, you could have some code run in the default dispatcher with multiple threads, but then use a value produced by that code to update some UI in the UI thread. In that case, you're not looking for concurrency, the computation on the default dispatcher has to happen before updating the UI because you need the result:

```kotlin
val result = someComputation()
withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
    updateUI(result)
}
```

Of course, even if the computation and the update of the UI are not concurrent, their sequence can be concurrent with other pieces of code:

```kotlin
scope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
    val result = someComputation()
    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
        updateUI(result)
    }
}
```

If you need to execute concurrent things, you can use coroutine builders like `launch` and `async`. However, using `async { ... }` immediately followed by `.await()` defeats the purpose of concurrency, because the code between the `async` and `await()` calls is precisely what will run concurrently with the `async`'s body:

```kotlin
val deferred = async { computeSomeValue() }
somethingConcurrentWithAsyncBody()
val result = deferred.await()
```

You can read more about how to organize your calls to achieve concurrency in the part of the doc about [composing suspend functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/composing-suspending-functions.html).

Comment: Thank you, this really helped clear things up, could you explain what happens in your last piece of code about the async{}.await()?

Comment: @extremeoats when you call `async{}`, a new coroutine is started and runs concurrently with the current coroutine. The code in the body of `async` executes "at the same time" as the code that follows the `async{}`. Calling `await()` suspends the current coroutine so that it waits for the receiver `Deferred` to be complete - meaning it waits for the body of async to finish execution. So, if you call async to start a concurrent computation, but then you immediately stop and wait for it instead of doing something while it's working, you don't make use of concurrency. Is that clearer?